# Any other quality references for Flask login management out there?

Tags: flask, flask-login, change-password, forgot-password, flask-mail

Beginners find many quick construct templates and tips to get started with basic flask-python applications but it is very dry for complete ones. A complete app needs minimum login functionality and password management. Max Halford boilerplate is high quality (https://github.com/MaxHalford/flask-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md) Other fine references are welcome.

I have tried PythonAnywhere, Lynda and most of stackoverflow. All fine with basic starters, but not minimum login and password management examples.

Password change and forgot password are minimum elements of password management.

Any other fine references out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first go-to should probably always be the documentation. 
[Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io) , [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/).

the best overall comprehensive example of what i'm assuming you're looking for in this case can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH).

the tutorial covers everything from building your flask app from scratch through deployment. enjoy!

Comment: More examples of flask will be welcome. There are still too few to make it more competitive vs. Django